# Try-Except неправильно работает

Tags: delphi

Есть sql-скрипт создания юзера на сервере firebird. После успешного создания пользователя на сервере запись вставляется в БД в таблице `users`. В случае ошибки после оператора `ExecuteAll` управление передаётся на оператор `Fmain.qUsers.insert`, т.е. всё равно делается вставка в пользовательской таблице `users`. Получается что пользователь сервера не создан а вставка в таблице БД `users` произошла.

```
//создание пользователя на сервере
if editNewPassw.text = '' then
  editNewPassw.SetFocus
else
begin
  TRY
    with Fmain.FDScript1 do 
    begin
      SQLScripts.Clear;
      SQLScripts.Add;
      SQLScripts[0].SQL.Add('create user ' + editUserName.Text + ' ' + 'password ' + #39 + editNewPassw.Text + #39);
      ValidateAll;
      ExecuteAll;
    end;
  EXCEPT
    Application.MessageBox('Error!', '', MB_ICONERROR);
    exit;
  END;
end;

//вставка пользователя в бд в таблице users
Fmain.qUsers.insert;
Fmain.qUsersUser_name.AsString := Editusername.Text;
Fmain.qUsersuser_passw.AsString := EditRepeatNewPassw.Text; 
fmain.qUsersRole_id.AsInteger := fMain.qRoles.FieldByName('role_id').AsInteger;
Fmain.qUsersDtCreate.AsDateTime := now;
Fmain.qUsers.ApplyUpdates;
close;
end;
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что выполняется `Application.MessageBox('Error!','',MB_ICONERROR);`, а потом `Fmain.qUsers.insert;`? Это маловероятно.

Comment: @Igor, Application.MessageBox('Error!','',MB_ICONERROR); не выполняется, сразу переходит на Fmain.qUsers.insert;

Comment: Т.к. используемый компонент не указан смею предположить что он не создает эксепшн при неудачном запросе вида "executeAll" и тогда логично описаное поведение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите сказать, что выполняется `Application.MessageBox('Error!','',MB_ICONERROR);`, а потом `Fmain.qUsers.insert;`? Это маловероятно.

Гораздо хуже, что Вы вставляете запись при пустом  `editNewPassw`.

```
if length(editNewPassw.text) = 0 then 
begin
  editNewPassw.SetFocus;
  exit;
end
else
begin
  ...
```

---

> Application.MessageBox('Error!','',MB_ICONERROR); не выполняется,
>   сразу переходит на Fmain.qUsers.insert;

Хм, хорошо. Откуда тогда Вы знаете, что произошла ошибка при выполнении `ExecuteAll`?

---

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.ExecuteAll

> The exceptions raised at the script command executions are not
>   propagated outside the ExecuteAll method. To check the script
>   completion status, use:

то есть

> Исключения, возникшие во время выполнения скриптов, не выходят наружу
>   ...

```
if not ExecuteAll then
begin
  Application.MessageBox('Error!','',MB_ICONERROR);
  exit;
end;
```

Comment: поставил breakpont-ы. 
например при создании юзера использовал неанглийские символы тогда delphi выводит: "'Project raised exception clss EIBNativeException with message ''[FireDAC][Phys][FB]Dynamic SQL error'"

Comment: вы спросили откуда знаю, что произошла ошибка при выполнении ExecuteAll, я ответил что поставил breakpoint-ы и приводил пример когда происходит исключение и текст что delphi выводит.  
P.S. delphi 10.2 у меня.

Comment: @Delphi159 Вы же понимаете, что если Вы не попадаете в `except`, то исключения не происходит, или оно съедается внутри `ExecuteAll`.

Comment: @Igor чего бы ради? Вполне себе поддерживает... просто строка по умолчанию в нем ASCII.... и все компоненты написаны с этим учетом... но WideString в нем вполне себе присутствует, работает, и может быть успешно использован .....

Comment: @Igor а почему тогда delphi выводит: "'Project raised exception clss EIBNativeException with message ''[FireDAC][Phys][FB]Dynamic SQL error'"?
exception разве не тсключение? 
Как изменить код чтобы при ошибке создания юзера сервера не происходила вставка в таблице users?

Comment: Дочитайте комментарии... "оно съедается внутри" вам выше это написал @Igor

Comment: Или если попробовать создать юзера который уже существует на сервере выводит: Project raised exception class EIBNativeException with message '[Firedac][phys][FC] add record error violation of primary or unique key....
Но всеравно управление переходит на fMain.qUsers2.insert; и юзер в б добавляется!!!

Comment: Потому что в опциях проекта у Вас стоит "Break on exception" и то, что сказал @ВладимирКлыков.

Comment: Cобственно говоря, все, что требуется, - это читать документацию, ссылка в ответе.

Comment: @igor, прочитал, спасибо! т.е. через скрипт не получится. 
А как можно по-другому решить эту проблему т.е. вставку в таблице бд только при успешном создании пользователя сервера?

Comment: Так  работает: if  fMain.FDScript1.ExecuteAll then
        begin
          fMain.qUsers2.open;
          fMain.qUsers2.insert;
         ..........
          fMain.qUsers2.ApplyUpdates;
          close;
        end
        else
        begin
          Application.MessageBox('Error!','',MB_ICONERROR);
           exit;
        end;

Comment: @Delphi159 Я же написал Вам вариант в ответе.

Comment: @Igor, спасибо!